# How to enable template while creating node

Tags: 7, theming

I want to enable different template for different node while creating node.
for eg: I am creating blog1 node, then while creating blog1 node I should be able to choose template in drupal 7.

Please help to achieve these functionality

Answer (score 1):

Create a **node--[content-type].tpl.php** file.

Add select list field as new field to your content type.

Then in the template file you just check with an if statement.

If select list field = x then ...

.
.
.
.

else if select list field = y then...

.
.
.
.